# Per Capita Income data of states in the USA

Tags: econometrics, data-request

Where can I get Per Capita Income data of states in the USA? Also which are the sources often used in econometric or macroeconomic analysis and how reliable are they?

Comment: It's not clear but I think maybe you're asking for data *for each state*, [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_income#States_and_territories_ranked_by_per_capita_income)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEA Person Income per capita for USA or states

https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?acrdn=5&isuri=1&reqid=70&step=1

St Louis FED can pull up this data for you.
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A792RC0A052NBEA

[image]

For your second question, it really depends on how you define personal income.  A recommendation is to check the statistical agencies definition of personal income and see if it matches up with your analysis/ project.